# Keycloak Direct Grant API and Admin REST API

Tags: authentication, jboss, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I am creating a mobile application which will talk to my REST Web Services, for `login`, `GET`, `POST`, `DELETE` and `logout`. I have been trying to figure out how to secure these REST Web Services using Keycloak. I do not want any In Browser Login on the mobile application, so I was inclined towards Direct Grant API and Admin REST API for authentication and token validations. But, now after looking at the available options on Keycloak, every request from the mobile app must be intercepted, and then make a REST call to the Keycloak module for validating the token and then return a response back to the mobile app.

Is there a better way in doing this? Some inbuilt function calls to check the token validity instead of making an HTTP call for every request from the mobile app? I think this is a huge overhead.

My server is on JBOSS. Spring, Resteasy and Keycloak-services are being used to figure out a solution for this problem.

Comment: Did you tried [JBoss AeroGear](https://aerogear.org)? Among other features AeroGear offers integration for KeyCloak oAuth2 implementation. Take a look in the [Aero Gear OAuth2 Guide](https://aerogear.org/docs/guides/security/oauth2-guide/)